# grep for files containin specific text in a specific line at a specific position

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I need to grep for filenames of files that have certain string ("OB") in a certain position (7-8) of a certain line (line 1) of the file.

What is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `head` to get the first line of each file, then `grep` with a corresponding regexp and output the line before to retain the filename:

```
head -n1 * | grep -EB1 '^.{6}OB'
```

Of course, you have to change the file selection - here `*`- to suit your needs.

**Update:** Question was updated - If you just want the filenames, just add another grep to catch the filenames given by the `head` command:

```
head -n1 * | grep -EB1 '^.{6}OB' | grep '==>'
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using `awk`..

```
awk 'FNR == 1 && /^.{6}OB/ {print FILENAME; nextfile}' *
```

Comment: +1 I prefer this way. because if the `certain line` is not `1`, e.g. changed into `42` the `head` answer must be adjusted (with tail for example).  Note that, it is also handy combine `find` first to narrow the files down then pass to other tools, awk here. `find` will dig files recursively in some situation, it is nice.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` might be better for this job:

```
line=1
pos=7
len=2
awk "FNR==${line} && substr(\$0,${pos},${len})=='OB'{print FILENAME}" myfiles
```

Or alternatively:

```
awk -vl=${line} -vp=${pos} -vn=${len} 'FNR==l && substr($0,p,n)=="OB"{print FILENAME}' myfiles
```